# Use const of base class on initialization

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, constants

Let's assume there is a base class with a constant value, an intermediate child class that derives from the base, and a final derived class which derives from the intermediate class.

If we want to use the constant in the derived class's initializer list, how one would be able to do that?

Here is a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
    protected:
        const std::size_t c;

        Base() : c(64){}
};

class Intermediate : public Base{
    public:
        Intermediate(int val){
            std::cout << "In Intermediate c is " << c << std::endl; // In Intermediate c is 64
            std::cout << "However, val = " << val << std::endl;     // However, val = 10
        }
};

class Derived : public Intermediate{
    public:
        Derived(int val) : Intermediate(this->c+val){
            std::cout << "In Derived c is " << c << std::endl;      // In Derived c is 64
        }
};

int main(){
    Derived instance(10);

    return 0;
}
```

The desired output is 74, however c has not been initialized when the Derived class's initializer list is called.

Possible solutions I see are:

1. Make the const static
2. Create a setter method
3. Multiple inheritance

However, I'd like to keep the overall structure as is (initializer list) and no constructor body, so **how can one use a const from a base class during initialization?**

Comment: since you used this value before constructor was processed. You've used `c` symbol as a argument of constructor and as a result you have created a chicken-egg problem.

Comment: @MarekR this is not chicken-egg: the *calculation* to be performed on base is known in advance and thus can be passed to Intermediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want a protected ctor in Intermediate that accepts a Base visitor. You can then provide any kind of visitor (=calculation) on base that can be used by Intermediate and thus have multiple descendants. You can even make this a static visitor via templates.

```
class Intermediate {
public:
    Intermediate(int val) { ... }

protected:
    template<typename V>
    Intermediate(V vis)
        : Intermediate(vis(*static_cast<const Base*>(this))) {}
};

class Derived {
public:
    Derived(int val)
        : Intermediate( [&](const Base& base) { return base.c + val; }) { ... }
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be an overkill if I'm just interested in that const value, and everything else is properly solved with inheritance?

Comment: Overkill maybe, overhead not at all. If your team is not used to functional programming and you have other possible design(s) (e.g. static, enum-based ctor, etc.), you might want to skip this. (2 in your list I'd skip and 3 I don't see how is being related). This is, however, general and can be used anywhere.

Comment: Well, this definitely is an overkill for my needs, but it is a different approach from the ones I proposed, so here, have a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

You've used this value before constructor was processed.
You've used `c` symbol as a argument of constructor and as a result you have created a chicken-egg problem.

Enable `-Wall` switch in compiler to catch such problems.
Compiler is warning you that you are doing something fishy:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/DIYaSQQ4FQQwsmkO

```
prog.cc: In constructor 'Derived::Derived(int)':
prog.cc:20:47: warning: '*<unknown>.Derived::<anonymous>.Intermediate::<anonymous>.Base::c' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
         Derived(int val) : Intermediate(this->c+val){
                                         ~~~~~~^
```

Proper way of fixing that is do not use magic numbers (in some way ti is this problem):
https://wandbox.org/permlink/1nfa3eXP2XIhgRE8

```
class Base{
    protected:
        static const std::size_t cDefaultValue = 64;
        const std::size_t c;

        Base() : c(cDefaultValue){}
};

class Intermediate : public Base{
    public:
        Intermediate(int val){
            std::cout << "In Intermediate c is " << c << std::endl; // In Intermediate c is 64
            std::cout << "However, val = " << val << std::endl;     // However, val = 10
        }
};

class Derived : public Intermediate{
    public:
        Derived(int val) : Intermediate(cDefaultValue + val){
            std::cout << "In Derived c is " << c << std::endl;      // In Derived c is 64
        }
};
```

Another way to fix it is composition. Sadly most developers have tendency to overuse inheritance where in most cases composition is better choice.

Comment: I'm aware this is wrong (I said that in the question). I would like to know a solution besides the ones I've proposed.

Comment: Funny thing, g++ (gcc version 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2) (GCC) ) is not complaining even using -Wall here.

Comment: interesting, it should warn about that.

Comment: Regarding my use case, Base class has a constant property that belongs to every child. I could make it static, as it seems to be the most reasonable approach (although I didn't understand why you created a second const, if a single would be enough for that), but would you say that using another approach is preferrable? (I'm thinking if composition is a suitable approach)